# Full-duplex HTTP connection

Tags: http, nginx

Is that possible to create Full-duplex persistent Http connection through 80-port with nginx  which proxies requests to other internal servers? It has to be done to implement bidirectional binary data streaming between desktop applications through 80 port of the Http server.

Comment: why does it have to be over port 80 if it's a desktop application?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need some kind of [HTTP tunnelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel#HTTP_Tunneling_without_using_CONNECT), or implement [XMPP over HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol#XMPP_via_HTTP_transport) in your application.